# Texture Paint Slot not showing up

Tags: texturing

Watched a couple tutorials on texture painting and for some reason they have a "Texture Paint Slot" tab that isn't showing up for me. Was it moved somewhere else?

[image: Tutorial]

[image: Mine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Blender 4 it's in the header bar:

[image]