# Texture slots menu item not showing

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender
I have got as far as importing my MSFS model, cleaning so I can only see the bit I wish to paint, and getting into texture paint mode. The tutorial Im following (and several others) then utilise a slot called "Texture slots" to create a texture layer on which to paint.
But where they show the menu item to do this, I see no item like theirs.
It is when I am in  texture paint mode and have the "Tool" button engaged (Screwdriver and spanner).
Sorry if my terminology is poor. But I sam completely stuck.
I'm using Blender 4.
Can anyone help.

Comment: Please add an image of your Blender window so that we can see what's going on. You can do that via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender and then edit your question and add the image to it with the buttons below your question.

Comment: Please use the search function of this site. Does this answer your question? [Texture Paint Slot not showing up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306298/texture-paint-slot-not-showing-up)

Comment: Hello, John, welcome to BSE. It does look as if this question has been answered already, so this can be fairly closed as a duplicate. If  the other answer doesn't work for you, edit this post to explain why, and we'll happily re-open for you.